# Clean up member history view?

Tags: mks-integrity

Is there a way in MKS Integrity to clean up the member view?  We have files that when you open the Member History view just look like massive spider webs.  It would be nice if we could click a revision, hit a magic button, and only see the revisions directly tied to that revision (i.e., one level out from it).  Does anything like that exist in MKS?  (obvious: I'm new to MKS)

Answer (score 2):

1. From the Member History window, go to menu **-> View -> Change Filter** to bring up the **Filter Revisions** dialog.
2. Modify the **Filter Revisions** based on whatever criteria you care about--in this case, probably based **On Branch**.
3. Click **OK**.
   The member history should now display a filtered member history.

Unfortunately, there is no functionality for a "single button filter by current branch".  If your organization has a current maintenance contract with PTC, you could have an appropriate contact log a feature request for this functionality on usability grounds.

**Disclaimer:**  I work in PTC Technical Support.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know all my colleagues have the same problem. I can only give you the hint that when you have the Member History window you can set a filter in the menu [View].

Better would be to have some right-click menu for that - but this might be something related to an external script?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dynamic Member History views you might also consider having always 2 dynamic Member History views open.

One as list that shows all.
One graphical with a filter enabled with View -> Change Filter

If you never close that graphical history view the filter will remain active
even if you restart the Integrity client.